# Google Analytics Dynamic gtag Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, gtag.js

How do I add a dynamic parameter to the Google Analytics gtag?  There may be a case where I want to pass in a custom dimension (Link) for a specific action and exclude it from different actions.  Below is an example in which I am trying to figure out how to generate a dynamic parameter.

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456"></script>

<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-123456', {
    'custom_map': { 'dimension1': 'Page',
                    'dimension2': 'View',
                    'dimension3': 'Page Area',
                    'dimension4': 'GUID',
                    'dimension5': 'Link'}
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.trackPageAction = function(pageObj) {

        gtag('event', 'page_view', {

            'event_category': pageObj.category,
            'event_action': pageObj.action,
            'event_label': pageObj.label,
            'Page': pageObj.page,
            'View': pageObj.view,
            'Page Area': pageObj.area,
            'GUID': <?php echo session('customer_id'); ?>

        });

        <!-- HOW WOULD I ADD A DYNAMIC PARAMETER?? -->
        <!--
        if(typeof pageObj.link != 'undefined'){
            gtag['Link'] = pageObj.link;
        }
        -->

    }

});
</script>
```

```
<!-- WITH LINK PARAM -->
<a href="#" onclick="$.trackPageAction({category : 'Navigation', action : 'Page Navigation', label : 'Timeline Page', view : 'you', area : 'Footer', page : 'timeline', 'Link' : 'http://yahoo.com'})">TIMELINE</a>

<!-- WITHOUT LINK PARAM -->
<a href="#" onclick="$.trackPageAction({category : 'Navigation', action : 'Page Navigation', label : 'About Page', view : 'you', area : 'Footer', page : 'about'})">ABOUT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object in javascript before passing it to the function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.trackPageAction = function(pageObj) {
    let options = {
        'event_category': pageObj.category,
        'event_action': pageObj.action,
        'event_label': pageObj.label,
        'Page': pageObj.page,
        'View': pageObj.view,
        'Page Area': pageObj.area,
        'GUID': '<?php echo session('customer_id'); ?>'
    };
    if(typeof pageObj.link != 'undefined'){
        options['Link'] = pageObj.link;
    }

    gtag('event', 'page_view', options);
  }

});
```